# Complex $z_1$ and $z_2$ such that $z_1+z_2 = 1 - i$, $\mbox{arg}(z_1) = \pi/3$, $\mbox{arg}(z_2) = \pi/6$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, such that:

$$z_1+z_2 = 1 - i,\quad
\mbox{arg}(z_1) = \pi/3 ,\quad
\mbox{arg}(z_2) = \pi/6$$

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Here's what Im doing:

Im replacing z₁ = (1/2 + i√3/2) then Im trying to find z₂ = 1 - i - z₁ , which is giving me z₂ = 1/2 - i - i√3/2 . But I'm not sure if thats the right way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Recall the trigonometric form of the [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).
Then 
$$z_1=a(\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3))=\frac{a}{2}(1+i\sqrt{3}),\;
z_2=b(\cos(\pi/6)+i\sin(\pi/6))=\frac{b}{2}(\sqrt{3}+i).$$ 
Now find $a,b\geq 0$ such that $z_1+z_2 = 1 - i$.

P.S. If you make a drawing you will easily see that such complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ do not exist. Why?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.

Comment: According to me, a = 1, b = 1. I'm returning them from polar form to standard one and then finding the modulus, which is giving me 1, on both of them.

Now what Im doing is taking z1 as (1/2 + i√3/2) and then trying to find z2 = 1 - i - z1. The result that Im getting is: z2 = 1/2 - i - i√3/2, which Im writing as: z2 = 1/2 - i(1 + √3/2), but I don't know if this is the right way to do it. I have no idea what else to do.

Excuse my stupidity!

Comment: @Tengi When you solve the equation $z_1+z_2 = 1 - i$ you have to separate the real and the imaginary part. For the real part you have $a+b\sqrt{3}=2$, for the imaginery part ,$a\sqrt{3}+b=-2$. Now solve the system. What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Tengi However note that $a\sqrt{3}+b=-2$ can  not be satisfied by $a\geq0$ and $b\geq 0$.

Comment: @Tengi Any further doubt?

Comment: Im getting a = -1 -√3 and b = 1 + √3 . If I haven't done it correct, could u pls show me the result?

Comment: @Tengi It is correct. But since $a<0$ the solution is not acceptable. $z_1$ and $z_2$ do not exist!

Comment: Huh! Thank you a lot for your time. Wish you all the best